# Difference between Html5 Webapp and Apk

Tags: html, cordova

So I've build a html5 Webapp and converted this to apk using Adobe PhoneGap utility. What are the differences between the traditional html5 Webapp and the apk file generated now? Does the apk file generated act like a normal android app developed using Java?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there is no difference between traditional HTML5 web app and the apk file you generated regarding the way your application works.

The apk file you generated using PhoneGap/Cordova is a simple Android app containing a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component that displays HTML5 web app you built. It means, your HTML5 web app is wrapped inside a native application and works inside that application the same way it works in your browser. However, there might be slight differences between different devices and Android versions depending which web engine being used for the WebView component in the device you run the application.

Answer (score 1):

@Adnan Topal's answer is right, and see below for some more necessary information -
When you have a requirement that native elements/hardware features of the phone/tablet devices to be included within your HTML5 web app, phonegap generated APK differs from your regular web app.
The phone/tablet's native features can be accessed only when an APK is generated via phonegap/cordova.